# How to denote the set of all probability distributions and its degenerate probability distributions?

Tags: probability-distributions, notation

Let $X$ be any countable set, and let $\mathbb{P}(X)$ be the set of all probability distributions over $X$. I have two questions regarding notation:

1. Is $\mathbb{P}(X)$ common notation to denote "the set of all probability distributions over $X$" or should I define the object explicitly? Also, does there exist another, more common, notation to define this object?
2. Fix any $x^*\in X$ and consider the unique probability distribution $p\in\mathbb{P}(X)$ satisfying $p(x)=1$ if $x=x^*$ and $p(x)=0$ else. Is there any standard way to denote such distribution?

Comment: I have never seen that notation.  If I ran into it, I'd guess it was an unusual way to write the power set.   For the second, I'd use  something along the lines of $\delta_x$ but I wouldn't regard that as a universally recognized notation.

Comment: I've more often seen the notation $M(X)$, or some variation on that. You can interpret the $M$ as standing for (probability) measure. You can find some examples by searching for <"M(X)" probability measures> on Google. I would find $\mathbb{P}$ confusing because one expects $\mathbb{P}$ as notation for an *element* of your set, i.e. for a probability distribution.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for your comment. For (2), I am now defining a function $\delta_{x'}\in[0,1]^X$ satisfying
\begin{gather}
    \delta_{x'}(x)=
    \begin{cases}
        1&\text{if }x=x'\\
        0&\text{else}
    \end{cases}
\end{gather}
Does that look fine?

Comment: @JamesMartin Thank you for your comment. I will probably use $\mathcal{P}(X)$ then, since I myself have never seen $M(X)$.

Comment: That notation looks fine, but I would be sure to define it when used.  Same with $\mathcal P(x)$ which, again, I'd take for the power set.